# React refactor simple input component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have multiples components who needs input value
so I copy/paste my following code on the render method :

```
 <input type="password"
             name="password" value={user.password}
             placeholder="password"
             onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}/>
```

And I copy/paste the handleChange method in all my component :

```
handleChange(event) {
 const {name, value} = event.target
 this.setState({
    [name]: value,
})
}
```

I would like to have input in a component and call it from all my components and then get input value to add it to my current state component

Do you have any solution ?

Thanks

Comment: I think you could wrap all of that in a single component called MyCustomInput and then think to manage that handleChange as a callback passing as props depending of what you need

Comment: you can pass the state as a props <component {...this.state}>

Comment: But if I update the state in child component, the parent will not update the new password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you wan't something like this:

```
class MyWrapperComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = { password: '' }
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const {name, value} = event.target
    this.setState({
      [name]: value,
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MyInputComponent value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handeChange.bind(this)} />
        <MyDisplayPasswordComponent password={this.state.password} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const MyInputComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <input type="password"
           name="password" value={props.password}
           placeholder="password"
           onChange={props.onChange}/>
  )
}

const MyDisplayPasswordComponent = (props) => {
  return <h1>Your secret password is {props.password}</h1>
}
```

Comment: Yes it's something like this but there is possibility to have generic input for password, email, firstname ...

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean?